# I can't access each cell of 'Columns(2)' unlike ''Range("B:B")' What kind of range is 'Columns(2)'?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get the whole second column in range("A1:B15").
Of course , I can use 'Range("B1:B15")' but the range may change according to the situations like different WorkSheets. So I need to get the range of the second column dynamically.

The following code I made first pops up an error(Runtime error 13: Type mismatch).

```
Sub test1()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Range("A1:B15").Columns(2)
        Debug.Print r     '// Runtime Error '13': Type mismatch.
    Next r

End Sub
```

I thought that 'Columns(2)' is a kind of range, each cell of which can be accessed one by one.
To my disappointment, here 'Range("A1:B15").Columns(2)' is not a normal series of range.
Though, 'Range("A1:B15").Columns(2)' has an Address: '$B$1:$B:$15.'
I couldn't understand this, at first.

To find out why the error occurs, I tried the following code.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim r As Range, TargetColumn As Range
    Set TargetColumn = Range("A1:B15").Columns(2)

    Debug.Print TargetColumn.Count  '//count is  1, not 15
    For Each r In TargetColumn
        Debug.Print r.Address       '//$B$1:$B$15
    Next r

End Sub
```

'TargetColumn.count' is not 15, but 1.
'r.address' is only "$B$1:$B$15.", not a series of "$B$1, $B$2, $B$3 ...."
So 'Columns(2)' is not a normal series of range, but only a single range like a merged cells of range("$B$1:$B$15").

To bypass the type mismatch error, I changed the code like this:

```
Sub test3()
    Dim r As Range, TargetColumn As Range

    Set TargetColumn = Range("A1:B15").Columns(2)
    ' get the range using the address : Range("A1:B15")
    For Each r In Range(TargetColumn.Address)   
        Debug.Print r.Address, r.Value          ' works well
    Next r

End Sub
```

'Columns(2)' is not a normal series of range but a collection of range areas. It does have an address, which can be used in 'Range(Address).'

For example, 'Columns(1).address' is '$A$1:$A$15.' and 'Columns(2).address' is '$B$1:$B$15.' 
So the 'Columns' object is a collection of each columns.
It is just like 'Union(range("$A$1:$A$15"), range("$B$1:$B$15"))'.
Therefore, we can not access directly each cell in 'Columns(2).'

Is there an easier and simpler way to get a column range so that I can access each cell in the column range?
I believe there must be a better way  than 'Range(Range("A1:B15").Columns(2).address)' or 'Range("A1:B15").Columns(2)' which fails to run. 'Range("A1:B15").Columns(2).EntireRow' returns the whole range of "B:B" which I don't like to use.

Comment: That is a very well asked question. While it is different to the one I voted for as a duplicate target, I believe the accepted answer there covers your situation perfectly.

Comment: There is obviously tons of ways but here is a funny one if you wanna stick to columns: 'For Each r in Range(Range("A1:B15").Columns(2).Address)'.

Comment: Your first code only needs **.Cells** and **.Address** to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add Cells : Columns(2).Cells

```
Sub test2()
    Dim r As Range, TargetColumn As Range
    Set TargetColumn = Range("A1:B15").Columns(2).Cells

    Debug.Print TargetColumn.Count  '//count is  1, not 15
    For Each r In TargetColumn
        Debug.Print r.Address       '//$B$1:$B$15
    Next r

End Sub
```

debug result

[image]

Comment: 'Range("A1:B15").Columns(2).Cells' is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want but maybe that's what you after

```
Sub test11()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Range("A1:B15").Columns(2).Rows
        Debug.Print r    
    Next r

End Sub
```

This will loop through the single cells of column 2 and it will not run into a run time error as the line debug.print r will take the default item of the single cell which is value, r is still a range though.

Comment: 'Range("A1:B15").Columns(2).Rows' is also useful in this case. I didn't think of it. Thank you for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using Resize & Offset will help:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Range("A1:B15").Resize(Range("A1:B15").Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, 1)
        Debug.Print r.Address
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It works! But I think it's a little complicated. I want a still simpler one. There should be one, I suppose.

Comment: Although I haven't found a scenario where this code would trump the columns solutions, I think it is not correct to downvote inspiring working solutions like this one.